# find views that are using a certain table

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

How to find all views that select from this table it is possible in oracle using this query is there anything the same in psql

```
SELECT name ,
type ,
referenced_name ,
referenced_type
FROM user_dependencies
WHERE TYPE   = 'VIEW' 
AND NAME = '<VIEW_NAME>'
AND referenced_type = '<TABLE_NAME'>;
```

Answer (score 1):

This query lists all views that are using table `table_name` (including views that are using views that are using the table, etc):

```
select distinct n.nspname as schema_name, c.relname as view_name
from pg_depend d
join pg_rewrite w on w.oid = d.objid
join pg_class c on c.oid = w.ev_class
join pg_namespace n on n.oid = c.relnamespace
where d.refclassid = 'pg_class'::regclass 
and d.classid = 'pg_rewrite'::regclass
and d.refobjid = 'table_name'::regclass
and c.oid <> 'table_name'::regclass
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from pg_views where lower(definition) like lower('%<TABLE_NAME>%');
```

would that fit?..

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution if someone is looking for it.

```
SELECT table_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.table_views
where table_name = '<table_name>'
```

and to get more information about the view you can then use the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.views and join it with table_viewson view_name from views and table_name from views.

Answer (score 0):

```
select table_name view_name
from information_schema.views 
where view_definition ilike '%table_name%' and
table_schema = 'public' and table_catalog='db_name'
```